# Are distinct open and close delimiters syntactically necessary?

Tags: c#, ruby, haskell, language-design

In making an analogy between smart quotes and programming languages, it occurred to me that distinct characters for opening and closing delimiters might not be necessary, but simply a choice in readability.

For example, arguments in [Ruby’s anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Ruby) use identical pipes to open and close. Haskell uses white space with extreme prejudice.

I am not asking if different *types* of delimiters are necessary — brackets for indexers, braces for blocks — but whether distinct open and close braces (e.g. `(` and `)`) are **syntactically necessary** in most languages, or simply a preference of the designers.

Comment: With "Ruby’s anonymous functions use identical pipes to open and close", you're referring to the `|`s in `ex.sort_by { |x| x - x.to_i }`, right?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to have just one delimiter (whitespace, as in Forth). So yes, it is indeed a matter of readability, nothing more.

Answer (score 10):

Not syntactically necessary, but if open and close delimiters are the same, it makes it difficult (or impossible) to nest things.  Exhibit A is the POSIX shell,
where

```
var=`command`
```

was replace with

```
var=$(command)
```

precisely because the **code with identical opening and closing delimiters does not nest**.

Comment: There is nesting: `echo <BT>echo \<BT>echo abc\<BT><BT>` (replace `<BT>` with actual backtick).

Comment: @ZyX But still ```echo `echo \`echo abc\`` ``` is less readable than `echo $(echo $(echo abc))`.

Comment: @dave4420 I can't argue that. I am just pointing out that problem «nesting with same open and close delimiters» is solvable.

Comment: What you've done is encoded nesting depth into the delimiter, representing the depth as a _unary_ number (with \` as zero and \ as successor), then decided to require 2^n-1 instances of successor rather than n. Horrible!

Answer (score 8):

Having distinct delimiters allows nesting. Ruby's block parameter list does not support nesting, so using the same delimiter is okay.

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++, bare braces can be nested, and open nested lexical scopes:

```
{
    int a = 42;
    {
        int a = 24;
        {
            printf("%d\n", a); // prints 24
        }
    }
}
```

Use identical delimeters and this is ambiguous:

```
|
int a = 42;
|
int a = 24;
| // Is this an open or close pipe?
printf("%d\n", a); // 24? 42?
| // could be a pair
| // of open+close
|
```

Given the prevalence of C syntax rules, there are likely to be many other languages with similar issues (perl, for one).

Answer (score 4):

```
print |foo|bar||
```

Could mean either:

```
print (foo(bar))
```

or

```
print (foo)bar()
```

Both of which are valid Haskell and have different meanings.  But you are asking whether it is in principle possible to tweak the language not to require that?

Well there is an unreadable thing you can do.  Instead of applying functions with juxtaposition, introduce a prefix, 2-argument operator for application, call it `*`.  Then:

```
foo (bar (baz quux)) bax
```

could be unambiguously written:

```
* * foo * bar * baz quux bax
```

Application and a single constant symbol is enough to encode combinator calculus, so, *technically*, no, you don't need parentheses at all (Turing machines don't need parentheses either).

But you can't just iron out all the parentheses into bars and have it make sense unambiguously.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this, but for posterity: The simplest interpretation of `* * foo * bar * baz quux bax` is as a stack-based language, in which case you've essentially replaced explicit delimiters with implicit ones, i.e. pushing and popping the stack, corresponding directly to the parentheses in (a fully parenthesized version of) the previous form.

Answer (score 2):

[Unlambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlambda) is an example for a language without brackets, braces etc. They are replaces by a single operator (the Backtick) which stands for "apply". Similar, in Haskell you can write `a $ b c` instead of `a (b c)`. So there are ways to avoid different delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it from the point of view of a developer writing a compiler, I think it's easier to use delimiters. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by *distinct delimiters*, but you could technically use anything you like as symbols in your language. Just look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) language here. Just look at how much easier it is to parse an if statement when it has opening and closing braces:

```
if (true)
{
    doSomething();
    thenDoSomethingElse();
}
```

as opposed to:

```
if true
    doSomething
    thenDoSomethingElse
```

Aside from the tabbing, how else do I show that I want both of those methods executed as part of the body of the `if`. The braces make it clear to the parser that it all goes together. The problem with languages that do this is the "dangling else problem":

```
if true
    if someCondition
        doSomething
else 
    doSomethingElse
```

You better make your parser smart enough to know how to match up that else statement. I think explicit delimiters make that easier.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, they're not necessary. There are other ways to indicate when a block is starting/ending. That being said, distinct opening and closing delimiters provide more information to the people reading the code at very little code. That information can not only help the reader understand what the code is doing, but also **what it was intended to do**.

As an example of this, many coding standards require braces around single statement if blocks in C.